# How do you do map an entity to an table in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use to use the following configuration to map an `entity` to a table with Entity Framework.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
}
```

But in Entity Framework 7 the function `ToTable` no longer exist. Does anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: It is look like Pluralize issue, I am not sure that is issue of EF 7, you could try this workaround. User instead of Users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>().ForRelational().Table(tableName: "Test", schemaName: "Map");
}
```